# React to plotly animation button

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

Is it possible to make a Shiny `observeEvent` or something of the sort for a plotly animation button?

That is: how can one detect when the animation button is pressed to display something else on the side?

We'd need a reference to the button, but looking at the HTML output, I can't find an `id` given to the button. I also tried using the plot itself to animate, but that didn't work either.

Looking at `?animation_opts`, I found the [list of possible attributes](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/updatemenus/attributes.js) but couldn't figure it out. I saw a reference to the `execute = bool` attribute, described as:

> When `true`, the API method is executed. When `false`, all other behaviors are the same and command execution is skipped. This may be useful when hooking into, for example, the `plotly_buttonclicked` method and executing the API command manually without losing the benefit of the updatemenu automatically binding to the state of the plot through the specification of `method` and `args`.

But I can't see how to call `plotly_buttonclicked`. And, actually, I don't want to call it internally, but simply `observe` when it is called by the user.

So, basically, given this example:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("p")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  p <- plot_ly() %>%
    add_pie(values = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
            frame = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))

  output$p <- renderPlotly(p)
  observeEvent(p, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    print(str(p))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd want to print something to the console whenever the user presses "Play".

Answer (score 0):

There's an event `plotly_animated` but it seems to be triggered only when the animation is finished (**EDIT:** It's not the good event; see my edit at the end).

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("p")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$p <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly() %>%
      add_pie(values = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
              frame = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
    p %>% onRender("
                   function(el, x){
                     el.on('plotly_animated', function(){
                       Shiny.setInputValue('anim', true)
                     });
                   }")
  })

  observeEvent(input$anim, {
    print("ANIMATION")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Otherwise, instead of using the plotly Play button, you can do a Play button in Shiny; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708762/how-do-i-link-a-shiny-action-button-to-a-plotly-animation-in-r/56736716#56736716).

---

## EDIT

In fact you found the good event. It's `plotly_buttonclicked`. Replace my code with:

```
p %>% onRender("
               function(el, x){
                 el.on('plotly_buttonclicked', function(){
                   Shiny.setInputValue('anim', true)
                 });
               }")
```